# Specs2 Result vs MatchResult

Tags: compiler-errors, specs2

I'm migrating to Specs2 2.

This used to compile

```
if(foo) {
    bar mustBe equalTo(1)
} else {
    skipped("foo was false")
}
```

but no longer does

```
could not find implicit value for evidence parameter of type org.specs2.execute.AsResult[Object]
```

What should I do?

Version 2.3.13

Answer (score 1):

The first line returns a `Matcher[T]` and the second one a `Result`. Those 2 types unify as `Object` and this is why you get such a compilation message.

To work around this you can use the following helper function:

```
def skipWhen[R : AsResult](condition: Boolean, message)(r: =>R): Result = 
  if (condition) skipped(message)
  else           AsResult(r) 

"my example" >> skipWhen(serverIsDown, "server is down") {
  1 must_== 1
}
```

There are also other ways to skip examples described in the [User Guide](http://etorreborre.github.io/specs2/guide/org.specs2.guide.HowTo.html#Mark+a+block+as+pending):

```
"my example is skipped" >> skipped {
  sys.error("boom")
  ok
}

"this will skip if the expectation is false" >> {
   1 must beEqualTo(2).orSkip
}

"this will succeed if the condition is false" >> {
   1 must beEqualTo(2).unless(condition)
}

// this will skip all the examples in the specification if the condition is true
skipAllIf(condition)
```